# QTabWidget - how to "include" a pointer to every tab?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I'm trying to make a simple communicator, with UI based on tabs (QTabWidget). I want tabs to be closeable and movable. Still, for every tab I would like to remember a pointer to my class (where I keep socket etc.), so I could manage closing tabs and disconnecting sockets.

One way is to keep them(pointers) in array / any container, analyze any move that was done by a user, and change indexes or swap pointers dependently on index of tabs, that were moved, but this involves a lot of work, and even more bugs. Is there any other and simpler way I could get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `myTabWidget->widget(index)`.

There is one for each tab.

[Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#widget)

You can set the widget as the parent of your class if your class inherits from `QObject`, or connect its signals (like `destroyed()`) with that of your class.

Or you can even do

```
QVariant prop = QVariant::fromValue<intptr_t>((intptr_t)workerObject);
myTabWidget->widget(index)->setProperty("workerObject", prop);
```

to really store the pointer, and

```
QVariant prop =  myTabWidget->widget(index)->getProperty("workerObject");
WorkerClass *ptr = (WorkerClass*) prop.value<intptr_t>();
```

to get it back.